# Not a able to decommission the old datacenter

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 4.1 with Java 11. I have added the new data center and modified all my keyspaces including system_auth, system_traces, and system_distributed to replicate to new data center. Now I want to decommission the old data center. For that, I have changed all the keyspaces replication so that no data will be inserted in the old data center. while changing the replication strategy for system_auth keyspace, it throws an error

error: ConfigurationException: Following datacenters have active nodes and must be present in replication options for keyspace system_auth: [us-central1]

```
nodetool status:

Datacenter: us-central-1
Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving -- Address Load Tokens Owns (effective) Host ID Rack UN 10.41.0.39 3.29 GiB 32 100.0% da0dba24-f545-4a55-8167-9e76b55d951c f
UN 10.41.0.41 3.43 GiB 32 100.0% 79961e3f-78f5-470d-964b-e23ae40e489f e
UN 10.41.0.33 3.07 GiB 32 100.0% 7f1cfbe7-0bb7-4835-9f99-32df8062a251 d

Datacenter: us-central1
Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving -- Address Load Tokens Owns (effective) Host ID Rack UN 10.41.0.30 3.94 GiB 32 0.0% 45d528b4-f143-4981-a5db-fa730e568c0c c
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Cassandra (I think this started with 4.0) protect against accidentally removing replication of the `system_auth` keyspace to a data center.

This makes sense, because queries to the `system_auth` keyspace happen with a consistency level of `LOCAL_QUORUM`, so when the keyspace is not replicated to a data center, authentication will not work in this data center.

So, when decommissioning a data center, the correct way is first reducing the replication factor of `system_auth` for this data center to one. After this all except one nodes in the data center can be removed with `nodetool decommission`. When running this command for the last node, there will be an error:

```
nodetool: Unsupported operation: Not enough live nodes to maintain replication factor in keyspace system_auth (RF = 1, N = 1). Perform a forceful decommission to ignore.
```

So, in order to decommission the last node, one has to run `nodetool decommission --force`. This may result in a warning message like:

```
WARNING: Failed to check the connection: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM
```

This is the result of authentication in this data center not working any longer as soon as the last node becomes unavailable. The node should still be decommissioned, which can be verified by checking Cassandra’s `system.log` or running `nodetool status` on a node in a different data center.

Finally, the decommissioned data center can be removed from the replication configuration for the `system_auth` keyspace. After the last node for the data center has been removed, Cassandra will no longer complain about the data center having active nodes.